# K&R Exercise 5-5 strcpy Segmentation fault

Tags: c

im working my way through the K&R C programing language book and trying to implement my own version of the function strncpy according to the description in exercise 5 at chapter 5:

> strncpy(s,t,n) copies at most n characters of t to s

I have tried to write the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void *strn_cpy(char *dest, const char *src, int n){
    while ((*dest++ = *src++) && n--);
}

int main(){
    char * s1 = "hello";
    char * s2 = "abc";
    strn_cpy(s1, s2, 2);
    printf("%s", t1);
}
```

The code above returns a Segmentation fault error and I cant seem to figure out why,
the way I understand the function is that with each iteration of the loop, the current value of *src is copied onto *dest, afterwards both pointers locations are incremented by 1. Then, if the value of *src is equal to '\0' or if n equals to 0 then the loop breaks.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to guess that `t1` should be `s1`? Otherwise this won't even compile. And in that case you are trying to modify string literals, which is *undefined behavior*

Comment: `while ((*dest++ = *src++) && n--);` ==> `while (n-- && (*dest++ = *src++));`. Think what happens when the remaining size is `0`, but you haven't yet reached the string terminator.

Comment: char *s1 = "some string" will be put in read-only data segment. Try with char s1[] = "hello and space for whatever to copy here"

Comment: First of all you should have enough memory allocated in the destination that it can fit the source string you're copying to it. Secondly your variables `s1` and `s2` are only *pointer* to some memory, and that memory is the two arrays that contains the literal strings (and the arrays include the string null-terminator). Those string-literal arrays can *not* be modified, they are in essence *read only*. And this is the reason you should always make it a habit to use `const char *` when pointing to literal strings.

Comment: ... cont'd from above) because when you test  `n` to be `0` you have already overrun the buffer.

Comment: I find it weird that the book doesn't mention that literal strings are not allowed to be modified. Attempting to modify any constant or other read-only data leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char *s = "some string"` creates a pointer to a string literal that you cannot change. You're getting a seg fault because you're trying to write to a read only string. Change it to `char s[number]`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void *strn_cpy(char *dest, const char *src, int n) {
    while (n-- && (*dest++ = *src++));
}

int main() {
    char s1[6] = "hello";
    char *s2 = "abc";
    strn_cpy(s1, s2, 2);
    printf("%s", s1);
}
```